# Duplicate Class Found error in android studio, what should I do ? I don't even know what caused the problem

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses FAILED

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vB4HY.png)

dependencies >>

[image]

[image]

top level gradle file >>

[image]

I added safe args dependencey, made a class Parcelable, And I was navigating using navigation component

Comment: try to invalidate cache and restart,

Comment: I tried but it didn't solve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved a similar issue recently. The error means that there is a conflict between two versions of the the library displayed (jakarta.activation-api).

Check all your dependencies in your project (also check the version numbers) to verify that there is anything inconsistent. Also check the internal dependencies of your libraries, it may happen that you are using a third party library with a different version number and when the project is compiling it detect the duplication with different versions.

Comment: I've edited my question and added my dependencies, please check it out and tell me if there is an issue with it

Comment: @Mickey You have verified that the safeargs dependency is causing the error? In case you are sure it is the library causing the error I would add the following line in the build.gradle file exclude(module = "jakarta.activation-api")

Comment: I'm not sure if safeargs what causes the issue. what I changed in the code before applying changes are safe args .. parcelizing a class to share it to other fragments .. using viewmodelfactory to pass a value inside viewmodel .. that's everything I've done 

where to put that line please ?

Comment: Ok, so if you are not sure what is causing the error I recommend you isolating the error. It could take a while but you will discover what dependency is causing the error. So, start commenting some of your dependencies and try to build again, this is a trial and error procedure but at the end you should be able to discover the wrong dependency

Comment: I finally knew what was causing the problem 

id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.10' apply false

this was version 1.7.20 which was used somewhere else with version 1.8.10 so when I changed it to 1.8.10, everything worked fine. thank you so much, your answer really helped me to figure out where the error is.